# Is there a WP function to get taxonomy name from taxonomy_term_id?

Tags: functions, taxonomy, wpdb, sql

I need to get the taxonomy name from the taxonomy_term_id.

I am currently using the following to get it:

```
global $wpdb;
$term_taxonomy_table = $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy";
$taxonomy = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT taxonomy FROM $term_taxonomy_table WHERE term_taxonomy_id = $tt_id"));
```

I was wondering if there is wordpress function that replaces that SQL query? I like to avoid using SQL queries.

If there isnt, please tell me if the SQL query I am using is correct and safe. Thank you.

Comment: As far I know, the taxonomy name is always required to fecth a term object. See [get_term()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) and [get_term_by()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by). Just curious, can you explain a situation where you know a term_taxonomy_id but not the taxonmy which it belongs to? If you are in the archive of the taxonomy or term you could use `get_query_var( 'taxonomy' )` to get the current taxonomy name.